# Is there Social Desktop provider other than openDesktop?

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu, facebook, online-accounts

Is there a provider for Orkut or Facebook?

I mean a provider to add to this screen :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the blog entry [KDE Social desktop](http://www.open-collaboration-services.org/) there is only one provider at the moment (as of October 2012). This might change in future releases.

If you want to use Facebook, you should add the Facebook plasmoid.